# SVG Downward Inner Bevel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, svg

I am trying to reproduce this image as SVG:

[image]

It was made in Photoshop simply by creating a rounded rectangle and setting an inner bevel layer style, downward.  (It's a bit hard to see on this site, as it is meant to typically be shown on a darker background, but the beveled border is there.)

Is it possible to reproduce this effect with SVG?  I have experimented with setting a stroke with gradient, but it doesn't seem to look correct.  I am using Inkscape, but I can also get access to Illustrator or edit the SVG file directly.  Any help with getting the border style correct (or close to it) would be most appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I would do it:

- create your shape (rounded rectangle)
- duplicate the shape (so it's directly on top)
- give the one on top a transparent fill and a border color (doesn't matter what border color)
- adjust the width of the border stroke to be the width of your bevel
- choose PATH --> OBJECT TO PATH and then PATH --> PATH TO OBJECT
- your border is now a fillable shape. Give this shape a transparent border
- fill this shape with a gradient. Adjust the gradient so that it has a narrow transition from light to dark
- have this gradient's transition bisect at the lower left and upper right

Quick sample done in Inkscape:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DA01.  I am actually able to give a gradient to the stroke without duplicating the object.  This works well, but it doesn't quite achieve the same effect.  I think if I set a slight blur on it, it is closer on the inner edge, but then I need a mask of some kind to make the outer edge hard.  I will keep working on it.  Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You could do exactly that...give it a blur, then place the entire thing inside a mask to keep the hard outer-edge.

Comment: Using this tutorial:  http://en.flossmanuals.net/Inkscape/ClipAndMask/  I was able to figure out the masking and come close to reproducing the desired effect.  Thanks for your assistance!